# JPA 2 in Jboss and criteria api

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria

Is there a working JPA 2 implementation for JBoss server? Or maybe there is some additional extension that provides JPA 2's criteria api equivalent?

Comment: Yes, that extension is called "Hibernate" :-) Seriously, though, what specific functionality are you looking for?

Comment: I have an specification object that holds search criteria inputed by user. I want to translate this specification object into a valid JPA query. 

As a temporal solution I utilize string builder and build this query by hand which doesn't seem right to me at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JPA 2 is fairly new, I'm not sure there is any working stable JPA 2 implementation for Jboss. You may consider:

- Integrate Eclipse Link (JPA 2.0 support) in Jboss
- Wait for Jboss 5.2. JPA 2 is expected with Hibernate 3.5 integration, announced in Jboss 5.3 (http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/jboss-development/2009-September/014844.html). Hibernate current release is CR-2.